# How do I set a value with WWW::Mechanize::Firefox when there are three <input> tags with the same name?

Tags: perl, web-scraping, www-mechanize-firefox

I am using `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` to automate some interaction with a web page. Evertyhing works well until I reach a page where I want the script to enter a specific value into an `<input...>` box. Unfortunatly, this page has three `<input...` boxes with exaclty the same name:

```
<input name="search_term" value="" class="inputbox" type="text">
```

The line in the perl script used to fill the value is

```
$mech -> field('search_term', $value_search);
```

Since the name *search_term* does not identify exactly one `<input>` tag, the script halts with this error message:

```
3 elements found for input with name 'search_term' ....
```

So, is there a way to indicate which of the three `<input>` I want to fill?

**Edit**

*ThisSuitIsBlackNot* points out that according to the documentation I should be able to set a third parameter to indicate which of multiple matching elements I refer to. Obviously, this third parameter is ignored so that

```
$mech -> field('search_term', $value_search, 1);
```

still halts with the same error message as without explicitely setting the third parameter.

Comment: Unless your inputs have IDs, the only way I can see to do this is with [`eval`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox#mech-eval_in_page-str-env-document). I can't test, but it seems like it should work.

Comment: I've never used `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`, but I'd consider switching to [Selenium::Remote::Driver](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Selenium::Remote::Driver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working with `eval_in_page`:

```
$mech -> eval_in_page(
  'document.getElementsByName("search_term")[0].value = "' . $value_search . '"'
);
```